# javascript: save a variable's value between calls?

Tags: javascript

I have some code that looks like this:

```
createEntity = function (imageSource, baseX, baseY) {
    tmpIndex = images.length;
    images[tmpIndex] = new Image();
    entities[tmpIndex] = new Entity;
    images[tmpIndex].onload = function () {
        entities[tmpIndex].ready = true;

        // How do I get the line above to use the value of tmpIndex
        //  that existed when it was created?
        // That is to say, I want the images[1].onload function to
        //  change entities[1].ready, not entities[4].ready
        //  (assuming I created 5 objects sequentially
        //   before any images finished loading)

    }
    images[tmpIndex].src = imageSource;
    entities[tmpIndex].x = baseX;
    entities[tmpIndex].y = baseY;
}

createEntity("images/background.png", 0, 0);
createEntity("images/pawn1.png",0,0);
createEntity("images/pawn2.png",30,30);
createEntity("images/pawn3.png",60,60);
createEntity("images/pawn4.png",90,90);
```

The problem is that when I load all 5 images sequentially, as the above code shows, my onload function triggers with the *current* value of tmpIndex, not the one that existed when the function was created. Is there a simple way to make it so that the entities[somenumber].ready is toggled appropriately?

Comment: store it in another variable that doesn't change

Comment: How about not changing the value?

Comment: a local variable inside createEntity function should do the trick

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to declare `tmpIndex` as a local variable. To do this change

```
tmpIndex = images.length;
```

to

```
var tmpIndex = images.length;
```

Comment: Beautiful, thanks. I'm not the world's best coder, so scoping sometimes escapes me. This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Why does `tmpIndex` have to be visible outside of createEntity function? If it doesn't, just declare it inside your function, like this: `var tmpIndex = images.length;`

Your `onload` callback will be able to read its value even after the `createEntity` function has finished executing because will keep a reference to the scope where it was created.

Every execution scope is different, so every time you call `createEntity` you create different scope and a different onload callback function which stores a reference to *that* execution scope, and therefore is able to consume variables defined there.

Comment: I know your answer came first, and seems to say the same thing as Code-Apprentice's, but his was easier for me to understand and implement. He explained why it was broken, and what to do to fix it, where you asked why it needed the scope it had and what to do if the scope wasn't important... my main issue was that I hadn't considered scope, and without that context your answer didn't seem to make as much sense.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly. Here's a working JSfiddle example catching onerror instead on onload : http://jsfiddle.net/bdn2775k/1/

Here's the revelant part :

```
//Don't forget to declare a local variable !
var tmpIndex = images.length;
```